# Chronicle Map - guaranteed field ordering when deserializing / serializing values to the map

Tags: chronicle-map, chronicle-values

This question was asked here regarding fields being swapped in the map:

[Question about values swapping places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68560316/chronicle-map-values-of-fields-are-swapping-places)

Has anyone used used the Group annotation option to ensure that the order of ser/der be respected when reading/writing to the map?

In the code below, before adding the Group annotation, the account and costPerUnit were being swapped randomly. Our tests so far are passing with this change.

E.g.

```
Kotlin code: 

interface PositionReport {
    @get:Group(1)
    @set:Group(1)
    var instrument: Instrument?
    @get:Group(2)
    @set:Group(2)
    @setparam:MaxUtf8Length(101)
    **var account: String?**
    @get:Group(3)
    @set:Group(3)
    var positionDirection: PositionDirection?
    @setparam:MaxUtf8Length(101)
    @get:Group(4)
    @set:Group(4)
    var position: String?
    @setparam:MaxUtf8Length(101)
    @get:Group(5)
    @set:Group(5)
    **var costPerUnit: String?**
    @get:Group(6)
    @set:Group(6)
    @setparam:MaxUtf8Length(101)
    var realisedProfitAndLoss: String?
}
```

Thanks